# Should I not have won a culture victory by now?

Tags: civilization-6

I've been playing Civ 6 as Tomyris for a while and thought I was comfortably winning a culture victory, but... the game seems to want to keep going without giving me the option to accept victory or play "one more turn".

My understanding of how to win a culture victory was that I need to have more visiting tourists than any other civ's domestic tourists, i.e. on the line "X/Y Tourists" on my row on the culture world rankings, the X needs to be bigger than the Y. Well, I'm past that point, and I'm wondering whether:

- this is a bug, or
- my understanding of the victory condition is completely wrong (in which case: what is it?!?).

Here's what it looks like - either it's my imagination or the circle next to my "297/252 Tourists" is stretching:

[image]

What's going on?

Comment: Did you actually enable the culture victory win condition when setting up the game?

Comment: @Nzall if it is not enabled, this screen does not show up.

Comment: @Nzall: I didn't _disable_ it... all victory conditions are on, as per the default settings.

Comment: An explanation for the downvote would've been nice. I'm still hoping this question will be useful to others encountering the same bug (as @toryan confirmed). By the way, I'm on version 1.0.0.229 (339082), as per the info on the bottom left of the main menu, with no updates showing on steam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should have won a culture victory. The requirement is that you have more foreign tourists (297) than any other civ has domestic tourists (251). In this case you would need 252 foreign tourists to win. It seems that quite a few people have had this bug since release, but perhaps not enough for Firaxis to be able to fix it.

Suggestions for what to do next:

- Try loading an old save from before you 'won' and see if it triggers correctly
- Report the bug on the Firaxis forums: https://forums.2k.com/showthread.php?4296383-Bug-reports
- Accept the moral victory and continue playing (or quit)

Comment: Thanks for confirming the bug, much appreciated. Thought I was going crazy, because I couldn't find anyone with the same issue. For what it's worth, I continued and won a religious victory (I was leading in all categories at this stage, it was only on Prince difficulty), which triggered just fine during a turn. I do still have the savegame from before the culture victory should've been triggered, so will offer that to the devs on the Firaxis forums.

Comment: Leaving this answer as accepted, but have posted another answer now that I've confirmed how to work around the bug and trigger a culture victory.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:**

The workaround to this bug, i.e. a culture victory not triggering despite meeting the requirements, is this:

1. **Load a game from a couple of turns *before* gaining more foreign visitors than any other civ has domestic tourists in their own cities.**
2. **Continue playing the game *without saving*.**

That's it. What messes it up is the act of saving the game on the turn before achieving cultural victory. And yes, you need a saved game (autosave will work, but if you miss it and autosaves don't go back far enough, you're out of luck) to be able to do this.

**Longer version:**

Almost 5 years on from a couple of Deity victories and I've finally had another go at playing. I wanted to go for some new achievements this time, and one was that I still hadn't won a culture victory. So, believe it or not, I ran into the same bug again. I'd been half-expecting that, so had saved pretty much every turn leading up to it (which, ironically, ended up causing the bug to manifest itself).

The next closest civ (also Kongo, for the "Selfie" achievement", hence it shows up twice in the screenshot) had 54 domestic tourists, so I needed 55 foreign tourists for a culture victory. I checked every few turns as numbers were creeping up quite quickly, and suddenly I had 58/55, but no culture victory.

[image: No victory despite meeting requirements]

A bit of googling showed various theories, one being that you had to hit the number straight on, so in my case get exactly 55/55, to get the victory. I disproved that by going back about 2-3 turns and gifting a bunch of my great works to rival civs so I'd produce less tourism output. I hit the requirement exactly and still didn't get the victory. Another theory was that sometimes you had to continue playing a few turns - that didn't work for me (but someone insisted it had worked for them, so... maybe they stopped saving and played on to trigger it, can't say for sure).

[This Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/obkqd1/how_have_i_not_got_the_culture_victory_yet_i_got/h3pqje1/) put me on the right track. I went back 3 turns, made sure I had fewer tourists than required, and just did nothing for 3 turns, not moving my units and selecting random techs or things to build. Sure enough, the game awarded me a culture victory and the desired achievements.

[image: Kongo and culture victory achievement]
[image: Selfie achievement]

Hitting the "Just One More Turn..." and checking the culture leaderboard showed that I had again overshot the requirement, but by *not saving the game for a turn or two*, it didn't glitch out.

[image: Victory after not saving]

I'm pretty convinced this is a bug, but maybe it could be some misguided attempt at stopping people from sharing a save game just before a victory. It's quite disappointing that this bug has been around for such a long time without getting fixed or officially clarified as a "don't save requirement".

I'll leave the original post by toryan as the accepted answer, but I hope this explanation helps others who encounter this particular bug.

Answer (score 1):

Are you currently at war? I tried making peace and then the cultural victory worked.

Going back to an old save didn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks, made peace, won right after! The second time this happened, the first time couldn't find a solution so went for science victory instead, but this was more satisfying.